# android studio cannot SetText from adapter

Tags: android, textview, listview-adapter

so im having this function in my custom listview adapter from CountDownTimer, but somehow i can't update the text to UI. Help me plz

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                long waktu = millisUntilFinished;
                updateTimeRemaining(waktu);
        }
    };



    private void startUpdateTimer() {
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }



    public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
        millisUntilFinished = (int) currentTime - 1000;
        if (millisUntilFinished > 0) {
            tempminute = (int) Math.floor((millisUntilFinished/1000)/60);
            minutes = tempminute%60;
            seconds = (millisUntilFinished/1000)%60;
            hours = tempminute/60;

            Log.i("myarc","00 day " + hours + " hr " + minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec");

            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    vouchercountdown.setText("00 day " + hours + " hr " + minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec");
                }
            });
            //vouchercountdown.setText("00 day " + hours + " hr " + minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec");
        } else {
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    vouchercountdown.setText("00 day 00 hr 00 min 00 sec");
                }
            });
            //vouchercountdown.setText("00 day 00 hr 00 min 00 sec");
        }
    }
```

but when i call it for the first time from the getView like this, the Text changed.

```js
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout_voucher, null, true);

        ImageView imagevoucher = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.ImageVoucher);
        vouchercountdown = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.CountdownText);
        final TextView soldcounter = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.SoldCount);
        TextView buybutton = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.BuyText);

        buybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countersold[position] += 1;
                soldcounter.setText("Sold \n " + String.valueOf(countersold[position]));
            }
        });

        updateTimeRemaining(Integer.valueOf(timeinseconds[position]));


        soldcounter.setText("Sold \n " + String.valueOf(countersold[position]));
        imagevoucher.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
        return  listViewItem;
    }
```

so why the textView can't change text from my startUpdateTimer code loop ?

Thanks.

Comment: and also when i tried to put  vouchercountdown.setText inside the buybutton.setOnClickListener the text not changed as well, and only the soldcounter.setText being changed. is something wrong with vouchercountdown declaration or else?

Answer (score 0):

I use to reformat Thread like below if UI is not being updated, Try like this

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {         
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                       
                       long waktu = millisUntilFinished;
                       updateTimeRemaining(waktu);
                       // OR textView.setText codes here
                    }
                });  
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: tried that but still not working, or is it because i use context.runOnUiThread instead just runOnUiThread ?

Comment: That's also possible, but It should work, maybe directly calling `updateTimeRemaining` in run not working. So you have tto put every UI updating code inside run method of my sample template. like setting the textview text. I hardly managed to make this work. Your one is also the same problem. You have to reformat these all.

Comment: i reformat all that but still the same, maybe the problem is somewhere else so i will look for another way while searching whats wrong, anyway thx shree